# How to know that job of AWS Comprehend finished?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-comprehend

I have a problem with comprehend: I need to know when job finished.
Comprehend has limit of 10 jobs. In order to run new job, I have to know about finishing old job. 
How may I do it?
Checking the creation of a file in the s3 output bucket is not appropriate, beacause when a file has already created, job has IN_PROGRESS status still about 2 minutes. And therefore I can't run new job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can periodically poll for the job status by calling describeJob API.

eg. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/API_DescribeEntitiesDetectionJob.html